# How to put all element into single column in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The csv file like as below column 1 for author name and rest of columns for authors book. data like

david, c-first,c++-first,java_2_test, ............ 100

smith,c_in_smit,d_programming_smit ................120

i need to put first colomn in author name and other in book column.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
# Load a text file and convert each line to a Row.
lines = sc.textFile("people.txt")
parts = lines.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
people = parts.map(lambda p: Row(author=p[0], author=(p[1]+ "," + p[2])))
# Infer the schema, and register the DataFrame as a table.
schemaPeople = sqlContext.createDataFrame(people)
schemaPeople.createOrReplaceTempView("people")
```

But the problem is the author book can be one or more .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the `split` method's other implementation like below:

```
parts = lines.map(lambda l: l.split(',', maxsplit=1))
people = parts.map(lambda p: Row(author=p[0], books=(p[1])))
```

Here, It split for only `one` time. So total results would be `maxsplit+1`

For more info on `split` refer [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

**-:EDIT:-**

If you want separate rows for each books like below:

```
+-------+-----+
| author|books|
+-------+-----+
|author1|book1|
|author1|book2|
|author1|book3|
|author2|book4|
|author2|book5|
|author2|book6|
+-------+-----+
```

You can change your code just as below,

```
def create_rows(temp_data):
    rows = []
    for book in data[1].split(','):
        rows.append(Row(author=data[0], books=book))
    return rows

parts = lines.map(lambda l: l.split(",",maxsplit=1)).collect()

people = []
for data in parts:
    people.extend(create_rows(data))

schemaPeople = spark.createDataFrame(people)
schemaPeople.show()
```

Comment: thanks @saurabh, if i need to break all books with author name like author_name , book_name as  <br/>a --  book1 <br> a ---book2 etc

Comment: @sansan, sorry I did not get it. Are you asking like you want data, like `authorName1-book1, authorName1-book2, authorName1-book3`.... in a single row?

Comment: ,your solution is perfect for  which i asked . i would also like data like <table><tr><th>author_name</th><td>book_name</td></tr> <tr><td>Author_1</</td><td>book_1</td><tr><td>author_1</td><td>book2</td></tr>  ; for each book in different row ; i.e in normalize form

Comment: yes but in different rows; in db 1st normalization form.